# Ecto: Group by result of fragment

Tags: postgresql, group-by, elixir, ecto

I'm trying to group records by a normalized date. The query works in SQL, but I have trouble translating it to Ecto. So far I have:

```
Invoice
|> where([i], i.club_id == ^id)
|> group_by(
  [i],
  fragment(
    "CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM ?) < 25 THEN to_char(?, 'YYYY-MM')
      ELSE to_char((? + interval '1' month), 'YYYY-MM') END",
    i.date,
    i.date,
    i.date
  )
)
|> order_by(
  [i],
  desc:
    fragment(
      "CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM ?) < 25 THEN to_char(?, 'YYYY-MM')
    ELSE to_char((? + interval '1' month), 'YYYY-MM') END",
      i.date,
      i.date,
      i.date
    )
)
|> select([i], [
  sum(i.gross_amount),
  sum(i.amount_paid),
  count(i.payer_id)
])
|> Repo.paginate(params)
```

This gives me the error:

```
expected at most one result but got 13 in query:
from i0 in KurabuApp.Admin.Invoices.Invoice,
  where: i0.club_id == ^"123",
  group_by: [fragment("CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM ?) < 25 THEN to_char(?, 'YYYY-MM')\n          ELSE to_char((? + interval '1' month), 'YYYY-MM') END", i0.date, i0.date, i0.date)],
  select: count("*")
```

An alternative approach I tried was:

```
Invoice
|> where([i], i.club_id == ^id)
|> select([i], [
fragment(
  "CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM ?) < 25 THEN to_char(?, 'YYYY-MM')
    ELSE to_char((? + interval '1' month), 'YYYY-MM') END AS grp_date",
  i.date,
  i.date,
  i.date
),
sum(i.gross_amount),
sum(i.amount_paid),
count(i.payer_id)
])
|> group_by([i], fragment("grp_date"))
|> order_by(desc: fragment("grp_date"))
|> Repo.paginate(params)
```

Which results in:

```
ERROR 42703 (undefined_column) column "grp_date" does not exist
```

The working SQL query is:

```sql
select   
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) < 25 THEN to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') 
        ELSE to_char((date + interval '1' month), 'YYYY-MM') END
        AS grp_date,
sum(gross_amount), 
sum(amount_paid), 
count(payer_id) 
from invoices 
where club_id = '123' 
group by grp_date 
order by grp_date desc;
```

What is going wrong here. The binding somehow doesn't seem to work and I don't have access to `grp_date`.

Comment: Could you try replacing `Repo.paginate` with `Repo.all` to see if it works? the `expected at most one result but got` error looks like a `Repo.one` called on many results, your fragment might not be the cause.

Comment: Indeed. Both queries work with `Repo.all`. Hmm, so it seems to be Scrivener who is the culprit. I still need paginated results though... Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Well I ended up writing the pagination myself...

Comment: I'm not so familiar with scrivener, sorry ^^'. My guess would be that it uses `Repo.one` on the provided query to compute the total count and this is messed up by the group_bys, something like that?